# How does whatsapp play youtube videos directly in iOS App?

Tags: ios

So since the recent update in whatsapp, you can play youtube videos using the default AVPlayer in iOS. 
I wanted to know how is this functionality possible? And if there is a way to implement this without violating Youtube's Terms of Service?

I know of tools like https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit but they clearly violate Youtube's TOS.

Check the screenshot below

[image: Sample Whatsapp Screenshot]

Comment: don't forget to consider that Whatsapp also could have custom contract with YouTube.

Comment: Use HTML: https://pastebin.com/p1GcUwCc  add it to `WKWebView`

Comment: @holex is there any way to know this for sure?

Comment: @suyashKD, unless you are insider, there is no way.

Comment: Hi @suyashKD did you find anything for the above one?

Answer (score 2):

One option that I don't know if the guys on **Whatsapp** use but I already used in a production App is a Pod made by YouTube guys, called

> YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper

You can see the link to the documentation below. With this Pod you can put a video preview in a UIView that helps but I don't know if is the best option to use because the Pod uses a Webview, injecting Javascript.

It's just an option... maybe there is a better solution for this problem.

Documentation link: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Comment: The thing is whatsapp plays the video in a default iOS Video player. I am not sure whether it is even counted as a view in youtube .

Answer (score 0):

I think Youtube API should available to integrate in your iOS app. Because normally in website youtube provide embedded api to play their video on other website. So, same for iOS also may be possible. Please check youtube's official developer website. You can Check this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper